# mysql bind-address change from 127.0.0.1 to server's IP Address breaks websites

Tags: mysql, localhost, mysql-replication

I'm trying to setup mysql replica. On master when I change `bind-address` value in `my.cnf` to server's IP address some of websites break as they are using `127.0.0.1` as database host value.

There are few other sites (WordPress) which work because WP uses `localhost` as db host value.

It is production server so I don't have liberty to change `127.0.0.1` to `localhost` on all those sites which break or experiment with changes.

Is there any other way by which I can keep mysql configuration `bind-address` value to be server's IP and it works with either localhost or 127.0.0.1 specified in the websites' configurations?

This is my /etc/hosts, some values are redacted

```
# cat /etc/hosts
::1     localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

127.0.0.1       localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
127.0.0.1       localhost ns123456

xx.xx.xx.xx     ns123456.ip-11-22-33.net ns123456
```

**Updates**

There is nice discussion on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19712307/mysql-localhost-127-0-0-1 however it doesn't provide a clear answer.

Comment: Are there mysql users for `username@127.0.0.1`, `username@ns123456.ip-11-22-33.net`, `username@server.ip`, and `username@localhost`? They are all distinct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When binding an IPv4 socket, the BSD socket API (used by most *nix and other OSes) leaves two choices: bind to a single address, or bind to *all* addresses using the reserved address 0.0.0.0 aka INADDR_ANY.

For your *mysqld* instance to be both able to be reachable by local clients using 127.0.0.1 (instead of the host's address) and remote replica servers which have to use the host's address, two addresses are needed. Either tell *mysqld* to bind twice, *if the version supports it*: one socket for each address, or else bind once to INADDR_ANY which allows all possible accesses.

From the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_bind_address):

> If bind_address is specified, its value must satisfy these
> requirements:
>
> - Prior to MySQL 8.0.13, bind_address accepts a single address value, which may specify a single non-wildcard IP address or host
>   name, or one of the wildcard address formats that permit listening on
>   multiple network interfaces (*, 0.0.0.0, or ::).
> - As of MySQL 8.0.13, bind_address accepts either a single value as just described, or a list of comma-separated values. When the variable
>   names a list of multiple values, each value must specify a single
>   non-wildcard IP address (either IPv4 or IPv6) or a host name. Wildcard
>   address formats (*, 0.0.0.0, or ::) are not allowed in a list of
>   values.
> - As of MySQL 8.0.22, addresses may include a network namespace specifier.

In case of doubt, just use 0.0.0.0. If the server has more than 1 interface or more than 1 address (in addition to the loopback interface) and you wouldn't want access to all of these interfaces and/or addresses, even then, adequate firewalling should already be in place, or else be put in place, to handle this case.